# Correct hyphen/style to use in bullet lists

Tags: itemize, enumitem, best-practices

I have several lists in my thesis document that look like this:

```
\begin{itemize}[nosep]
    \item 0x0000 - free cluster
    \item 0xFFFF - last cluster of the file (still including file data)
    \item 0xFFF7 - bad cluster
\end{itemize}
```

I'm using enumitem.

My question: how to style this correctly? I think my use of hyphens is not appropriate, but it looks strange with `\dots`. Is there a standard way to do this?

Comment: sorry, but your question is not clear. where you have `\dots`? standard way to write list is use standard itemize (without `nosep`), all others is customized. how to do this, is opinion based.

Comment: I think you want to  use `\begin{itemize}[label=\textendash, nosep]`. That is the usual French style for itemize-like lists. Some also use the `emdash` (erroneously, in my opinion).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want each item to start with the hex value, followed by (here) a hyphen, followed by text. 
I'd use an en-dash instead of a hyphen. The easiest way to get that is replacing the single hyphens by double hyphens ('--') which will be written as en-dashes.

You might also want to look at using the form `\item[0x000]-- free cluster`, where the optional arguments to `\item` will be right-aligned (but can flow into the left margin). Another option is the 'description' environment.